# wifi connection invisible in LTS 16.04 Gnome

Tags: wireless, router

I fresh installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS. The wifi has been working properly for a month up until yesterday when my home wifi connection(**router**) is not visible any longer(the wifi is visible in my other devices).
I can connect (ubuntu) using my **mobile hotspot**(it's visible) but the home **wifi is missing** in the "available wifi networks" menu.I can also use USB tethering.
I tried hidden networks too but unsuccessful.

The output of

$ sudo lshw -C network

```
    *-network



       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:12:00.0
       logical name: wlp18s0
       version: 01
       serial: c0:cb:38:94:ea:f3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:fbd00000-fbd03fff

  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:13:00.0
       logical name: enp19s0
       version: c1
       serial: 78:2b:cb:c7:7e:02
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:33 memory:fbc00000-fbc3ffff ioport:d000(size=128)

*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enp0s29u1u1
       serial: a2:b2:07:fc:a4:ae
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.208 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Comment: Try changing the channel the router uses to 1-11

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy31. It worked. Can u shed some light on why?